# Apache <Directory /> directive: get matched wildcard?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

Is there any way to use the string matched by a wildcard in an Apache <Directory /> directive further on in the configuration? Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    ...
    RUidGid $1 $1
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/$1/
</Directory>
```

…where `$1` is whatever was matched by the `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. Maybe right for you [mod_macro](http://www.cri.ensmp.fr/~coelho/mod_macro/) or ["Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html)